# Адаптив не работает на айфонах

Tags: css, адаптивная-верстка, iphone, адаптивность

`

```css
@media  only screen  and (max-width: 400px){
html, body {
        width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden auto;
 background-color: #4c66a2; 
}

    .content-wrapper {

    position: static;

}

.mob {


    top: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: static;

}}
```

```html
<div class="mob">
<div class="slide1"></div>
<div class="slide2"></div>
<div class="slide3"></div>



</div>
```

`Сделала адаптив, везде работает, на айфонах не работает.
В редакторе кода показывает, что должно работать на айфонах, а на настоящих айфонах не работает.
Адаптив сделан через медиа запросы.
Может есть какие-то тонкости адаптива на айфонах?

UPD: там есть меню, по нажатию на один из пунктов оно должно скролить до нужного момента на странице, так вот, если нажимать на пункты меню, то оно переходит на нужные раздел, но по-прежнему нельзя скролить

Comment: Не работает = взрывается телефон? :)

Comment: сразу сгорает:) не отображается часть кода. Показывает только самое начало страницы и листать вниз нельзя, хотя стили к началу страницы применяются

Comment: приложите код:)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ добавила код, на всякий случай вот сайт http://magic-performance.ru

Comment: он должен скроллиться вниз?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да, должен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что проблема в overflow: hidden auto. Overflow может быть либо hidden, либо auto. Указание сразу двух значений, по всей видимости, и приводит к некорректной работе.

Comment: да, оказалось дело именно в этом, спасло overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;

Answer (score 0):

Почистите ваш код - 2 раза открывается тег html и head, и закрывающиеся теги тоже посмотрите.
[image: Исходный код сайта]